# Stop the running threads from an array

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an array of threads and I want to start a few of them. The point is that I want to stop the threads with in a for loop.
In the for loop I want to check all threads if they are running or not, and if they are, I want to be asked if I want stop them(dialog box yes/no).

The problem is that the loop doesn't display all the times all three dialog boxes for all those three started thread. Sometime appear 1 dialog box, sometime 3 dialog boxes etc.

So, I do not have the chance to stop all three threads...

```
public class Main    {

    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        Counter[] arrayOfThreads = new Counter[10];

        for( int i = 0; i < arrayOfThreads.length; i++ )
        {
            arrayOfThreads[i] = new Counter( );
        }

        arrayOfThreads[3].start( );
        arrayOfThreads[5].start( );
        arrayOfThreads[2].start( );

        for( int i = 0; i < arrayOfThreads.length; i++ )
        {
            if( arrayOfThreads[i].getState( ) == State.RUNNABLE )
            {
                int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
                int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog( null, "Do you want to stop the theread: " + i, "Warning", dialogButton );
                if( dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION )
                {
                    arrayOfThreads[i].stopProcessing( );
                }
            }
        }

    }

}

class Counter extends Thread
{

    volatile boolean processing;

    public void run( )
    {
        int i = 0;
        processing = true;
        while( processing )
        {
            System.out.println( " Number: " + i );
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println( "finish" );
    }

    public void stopProcessing( )
    {
        processing = false;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

So all what I want is when I press the EXIT button to close the threads and to dispose the frame if all the threads are stoped. I modified the first class to more more clear.

```
public class Program extends Frame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Counter[] arrayOfThreads = new Counter[10];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfThreads.length; i++) {
            arrayOfThreads[i] = new Counter();
        }

        Program program = new Program(arrayOfThreads);
        program.startThreeThreads(1, 4, 5);
    }

    private Counter[] arrayOfThreads;
    private JButton stopThreads;

    public Program(Counter[] arrayOfThreads) {
        this.arrayOfThreads = arrayOfThreads;
        stopThreads = new JButton("STOP THREADS");
        closeThreadsWhenExitIsPressed();

        setSize(300, 200);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(stopThreads);
        setVisible(true);

    }

    public void closeThreadsWhenExitIsPressed() {

        stopThreads.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                stopRunningThreadsMethod();
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }

    private void startThreeThreads(int first, int second, int third) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfThreads.length; i++) {
            if (i == first || i == second || i == third) {
                arrayOfThreads[i].start();
                continue;
            }
        }

    }

    public void stopRunningThreadsMethod() {
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfThreads.length; i++) {
            if (arrayOfThreads[i].isAlive()) {
                int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
                int dialogResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Do you want to stop the theread: " + i,
                        "Warning", dialogButton);
                if (dialogResult == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                    arrayOfThreads[i].stopProcessing();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: please provide an [mcve], this doesn't sound like a real-world example. Or at least tell us your real use case. It seems somewhat skechty that you want to create and start threads and the close them immediatly afterwards

Comment: @Lino There's no problem with presenting a toy as an [mcve]. In fact that's sometimes the best way.

Comment: @Persixty I think it came over wrong, I wanted to encourage the OP to explain the use of his logic. As mentioned in the first comment, I can't really see a use for such a setup and thus I think the example given will not be very useful, although it seems the your answer has been accepted, so you've understood the problem, just I didn't :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for `getState()` is (my **emphasis**):

> Returns the state of this thread. This method is designed for use in
>   monitoring of the system state, **not for synchronization control**.

You're trying to use it for synchronization so you're already outside recommendation.
If you look at `Thread.State` you'll see it isn't always `RUNNABLE` and I suspect, as is common, `System.out` is synchronized so although not obvious from your code the thread could be `WAITING` (on another competing thread to use `System.out`).
Given all your thread does is hammer output it's probably quite common one or more is waiting. You could even find none show the dialog because as you go round the loop you happen to coincide with that thread waiting!
Check this by reading the state and outputting it!

So first, don't use `getState()` for synchronization and be aware you don't always know what synchronization is going on 'behind the scenes' in libraries you're using.
The documentation gives leave for the implementer to maybe cut corners in low-level synchronization of `getState()` and the value may not be 'first class' reliable (synchronized), but regardless don't do things you're told not to even if you don't know why!

The right method is `isAlive()`. The thread is alive if it has had its `start()` method called and not yet terminated. Waiting or not, it's alive...

Next problem, is because you set `processing=true;` in the `run()` method you could call `stopProcessing()` before `processing` has been set `true`.
There is no guarantee how far (if anywhere) down `run()` the thread has got when you reach `stopProcessing()` in the main thread.
I know there's a user interaction (e.g. big delay) but on an overloaded (or single threaded!) machine or a future use case it is possible for `processing=true;` to be executed after `stopProcessing()` sets it `false`. That may lead to 'runaway' processing.

So use `volatile boolean processing=true;` in the class declaration or set it in the constructor. That guarantees it will be set by the end of the constructor (takes place in the controlling thread) and must be before `stopProcessing()` is called.

Your application is (of course) a toy but think about when you would stop the threads the user didn't stop.

It's bad practice to just end the JVM without bringing all threads to a safe conclusion.
That doesn't matter in your toy but in real applications you may want to release external resources and (say) flush file buffers rather than let the JVM pull the run out.
That is, finally call `stopProcessing()` on all the threads in one loop and then `join()` in a second loop before ending the application.
It's important to use two loops because it makes sure the threads are all stopping concurrently and not one after the other.

I can't emphasise enough why you should end threads properly. People often ignore me and then long into to development have weird glitches that difficult to localise and hard to drive out.

Other considerations:

Consider using `interrupt()`. It's designed to help terminate threads and does nice things for you like jump them out of sleep and wait conditions (with an `Interrupted` exception). That will mean they may terminate faster (never slower) than your approach.
Again, not relevant in a toy but valuable in serious application.

Consider sub-classing `Runnable` instead of `Thread`. Again your toy is fine and valid but again 'real' applications end up preferring `Runnable` and using a thread pool of some kind (e.g. `ExecutorService`). That's clever because on many platforms the overhead of creating and destroying `Threads` is far larger than a lighter-weight `Runnable`.
That's the standard advice but I don't think its wisdom is always explained.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your answer. I want to use the previous code to close the running threads when the user choose to close the app. I modified a bit my post first post to bit mode clear.

Comment: @JohnR. But you still ask if the thread should end. If they close the app you should 


    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfThreads.length; i++) { 
      arrayOfTheads[i].stopProcessing();}
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfThreads.length; i++) { 
      arrayOfTheads[i].join();}
Not let the user let threads run into the buffers!

Answer (score 1):

The threads probably haven't started by the time you enter the loop in `main`. Their states are `Thread.State.NEW` when you check `arrayOfThreads[i].getState()`.

A simple solution would be either to wait some time before executing the loop to make sure the threads are running or to run a `while` loop over your loop to check the condition more than once.

Both are spotty and inefficient because you don't know exactly when the thread will be up and running. Instead, I would advise implementing a `wait-notify` mechanism to show a dialogue when the thread is certainly running.